# Learning to use dd to burn multiple images in a single USB drive

Tags: linux, usb, partitioning

I am tired of the GUI, there are sometimes problems and it is many times easier to do simple tasks from CLI. I am trying to burn 2ISOS so an USB stick.

So this is both about whether it is possible and how. But I have tried some already.

My idea is that it should be possible, and I have already copied the first iso (as bootable) on a 8GB USB.

The USB has plenty of space left. So I am trying to set a second one. If it goes wrong, it is not a big deal. But I wanted some expert input on it.

By running `lsblk` I see which partition is full and which is empty:

```
sdd      8:48   1   7.3G  0 disk
└─sdd1   8:49   1   3.4G  0 part
```

So I could technically write to a new partition under sdd1 using something like:

```
sudo dd if=/my/iso.iso of=/dev/sdd2 status=progress
```

Note I am using sdd2 for the new partition.

- Is this possible?
- dd you have any recommendation for the block size? (I do not understand that)

Comment: No, that won't work. It could be possible have multiple image on a drive (same partition or not) as **files** and use some bootloader to choose which to boot (the images themselves would need to have some kind of support for that), or have multiple EFI system partitions on a drive that consists of **files extracted** from images that supports EFI booting themselves (although I cannot rule out some UEFI firmware might have problems with multiple ESPs on one drive), but what are doing now won't make anything work.

Comment: For the record, `bs=4k` should give you good enough write speed on most types of storage devices, since usually the key is just to match the "block size" with the system "page size" (which is 4096 bytes on most systems).

Comment: Its a bit unclear what you are trying to do.  You can partition a dusk and then write an iso ti each partition - and then later recover them, but the partition ISO will not typically be bootable and yoy are likely better off writing to files on a formatted partition (which dd can do as well). BTW, ddrescue can be used similarly to dd but it can show progress and resume interrupted copies as well.

Comment: The thing is "raw writing" an image to a partition just for storage purpose does not make much sense (unless you have some kind of filesystem allergy whatsoever). If that's really the goal, make sure you partition the drive first (according to the file sizes of the images), and write each of the images to a partition (but not like write one to (the beginning of) the drive first and then add a partition for another).

Comment: @davidgo I want to have several bootable images in different partitions of an USB. In that way when someone asks me to try linux I can say "ok try these images" and hand a usb drive. It makes complete sense to me...I do not know what Tom Yan talks about tbh.

Comment: You can try Ventoy btw, especially if you are not interested in the details and/or don't know how to make things work by yourself manually. (I've never used it myself and have no idea how exactly it does what it does, but it *seems* kinda popular.)

Comment: You dont need to use partitions for the ISOs. You can write the isos as files and modern versions of GRUB can loopback mount the ISOs and boot them. (I assume this limits you to Linux distros though)

Comment: the isos themselves never boot, do you mean the "uncompressed" iso ? If so, it would not work to write them in the same partition as the would overwrite each other..@davidgo